# Post a photo on Facebook with restFB

Tags: facebook, api, restfb

How can i edit this code to post on my wall a photo that are for example in the directory:
"C:\myfiles\myphoto.jpg"?

```
FacebookType publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/photos", FacebookType.class,
  BinaryAttachment.with("cat.png", getClass().getResourceAsStream("/cat.png")),
  Parameter.with("message", "Test cat"));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local file access with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Comment: @Evan , how is this a duplicate?? Its a different question completely i think.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to replace `cat.png` in the code with your absolute image path.Something like this:

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\myfiles\\myphoto.jpg"));
    FacebookType publishVideoResponse =facebookClient.publish("me/photos",FacebookType.class,
            BinaryAttachment.with("myphoto.jpg", is),
            Parameter.with("message", "MY PHOTO POST"));
```